# HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 - Smart Storage Battery and controller issue

Tags: hp, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

My server machine is showing a couple of errors, I have read on HPE site and article says to replace the battery. Please someone guide in this regard.

However, my all four SAS drives indicating red led on the push button. This happened after error. Please check the screenshot. 
[image]

Server: HP DL380 G9
RAID 0, 4 Data Array(s), 4 Data Logical Drive.

Comment: What configuration of RAID was before breakage ? How many logical volumes were there ?

Comment: RAID 0, 4 Data Array(s), 4 Data Logical Drive.

Comment: What kind of write and read policies assigned to the array? Did you contact HPE support? Usually, there should be two options - reconfigure array (f1) and accept data loss (f2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your server setup, I'm very curious why you have RAID0 arrays configured. Please explain this, since it impacts the solution.

Loss of a disk in a RAID0 setup will cause that logical drive to fail.

Aside from that issue, you have a problem with the server's Smart Storage Battery. In many cases, array acceleration and some other critical features rely on that battery to function properly. If the POST errors are suggesting the battery be replaced, you should absolutely get a new battery.

Please power off the hardware, remove power cables, wait... then power everything back on again. Watch the POST messages for any changes.

The other thing you can try in the interim is updating the firmware of your P440 controller, disks, etc. in order to make sure the battery error is not a false positive. You can run updates using the [HPE SPP DVD image](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) or from the Intelligent Provisioning BIOS menu.

Comment: Well RAID0 was configured before my joining, and there is DC, and other services are running on it. So did not bother to change the RAID level.

Thank you, let me try to update the Intelligent Provisioning. If the issue exists after the update, I will purchase the Smart Storage Battery.